# Detailed online catalog of astronomical objects?

Tags: resource-request, star-catalogues

Is there a detailed online catalog of all the most important astronomical objects (stars, planets, constellations, galaxies etc.) with condensed data and photos? Something like this, which is taken from the Android app StarChart:

[image]

I'm looking for some website publicly accessible. I've Googled around a bit and was surprised of finding nothing relevant.

Comment: The SIMBAD database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The  [SIMBAD Database](http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-basicIdent=m33&submit=SIMBAD+search) is what you may be looking for, if you want a detailed online catalog of astronomical objects.

Basically, you have to type in a name/coordinate or a bibcode. For example, this is what I got upon searching up "Proxima":[image]

In case you want to type in a specific name like "HD 189733". You must have to type in the exact letters of the name, so that you can get the correct result.

And if you can't get specific data, like diameter, all you have to do scroll down to the "Collections of Measurements" section, and click on the "display all measurements" tab. That way, you can get a detailed, condensed information about the astronomical objects, like rot (I haven't figured out what that means yet), Fe_H (Has something to do with log iron abundance wrt hydrogen), distance from the Earth (in parsecs) etc etc. In short, you can use it to virtually get information on virtually anything in space.

> Not for me tho, I prefer Wikipedia =)